# Wordpress: Calling featured image as background image with custom size

Tags: css, image, wordpress, background-image

I'm currently calling the featured image for a particular post as a full-width background image for the header. In order to do this dynamically, I've inserted the CSS within the loop in the HTML.

This works great on a laptop/desktop, but for some reason the images aren't scaling for iPad — they're coming out huge.

Is it possible to add dimensions for the image (i.e.: width: 768px) to the following? I could then call it with a CSS media query to load at this size when viewing on an iPad.

```
background-image: url("<?php echo $image[0]; ?>");
```

Thanks

Added HTML code:

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-    post-thumbnail' ); ?>

<style>
.issue-header {
background-image: url("<?php echo $image[0]; ?>");
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your HTML is and I'm assuming you know how to run a CSS media query. I would suggest trying something like the following

```
#featured img{
    width: 80%; (or pixels if you prefer)
}
```

This will scale the image down to 80% width (and height) of any image within the featured `div`

Please provide further code such as HTML or possibly your website. I can probably assist you a lot better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Jester. Unfortunately resizing as you suggest changes the width of the entire div and not just the background image. 

I've pasted the HTML section in my original post.

I think the problem stems from the fact that I'm pulling the background image URL dynamically as the featured image of the post (the same set up resizes fine when the URL is static). It also resizes fine when changing browser size on a laptop — it's only on mobile devices and iPads that it doesn't resize properly (it's incredibly zoomed in).

Thanks

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am having the same problem, works perfect on computers, look ugly on mobiles... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background-size` property.

```
.issue-header {
background-size: 200px 200px;
}
```

or

```
.issue-header {
background-size: cover;
}
```

[See MDN for more info on background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).